# Spring Portlet + Thymeleaf: Bind object for ActionMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, portlet, thymeleaf

I've a problem with a Spring 4 Portlet using the template engine Thymeleaf.

I want to convert an existing servlet which is working fine to a portlet.
I use Thymeleaf for editing objects in forms in JSP files.

`<form method="POST" th:object="${object}" th:action="${portletActionURL}">
<input th:field="*{objField}"/>
...
<input type="submit"/>
</form>`

`portletActionURL` is a generated action URL which works so far. As you assume, I want to work with `object` in my controller. I tried many ways to realize that, e.g. the following:

```
@ActionMapping("saveChanges")
public void bla(@ModelAttribute("object") AnyDatatype object, ModelMap model, ActionResponse response, ActionRequest request) throws Exception { ...}
```

Unfortunately, object has not been populated its attributes after calling the action. I'm not really wondering about that but I don't know how to realize that using Thymeleaf.

I know about the option using `<form:form>`, but Thymeleaf couldn't parse the file with `taglibs`. I definitely want to use Thymeleaf because most of my JSP files use it and it probably costs to much effort to change every single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

I used the portlet in Liferay portal. While Liferay wants namespaced parameters by default I deactivated that in a liferay-portlet.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.2.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd">
<liferay-portlet-app>
<portlet>
<portlet-name>MyPortletName</portlet-name>
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
</portlet>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

Now, it works fine without changes to the code above.

Sincerely yours,
Julian